# High side switch with IRF9530

Tags: led, switching

Below is the design I used to switch the positive line of the WS2811 led with the TTP223.I want the led to stay on as long as I touch the sensor and turn off when I take my hand off. But when I power the circuit, the led lights up, when I touch the sensor, it turns off.  So it's the opposite of what I want.I find the solution by turning off the A switch on the sensor, but it doesn't make sense to me. Thanks in advance for the help [image]

Comment: WS2811 is an individually addressable LED ..  what do you have exactly?

Comment: I am getting data and ground from a led driver. I preferred this instead of using smd5050.

Comment: why don't you issue an OFF command to the LEDs instead?

Comment: I don't fully understand you but,  I want to do this from the sensor, not from the app

Comment: reprogram the TTP223 sensor module for inverted output ... refer to the datasheet

Comment: Normally, when I touch the sensor, there is a red LED inside, it lights up. It turns off when I pull it. If I turn off A, the led on the sensor stays lit until I touch it again.I'm wondering if this will harm the sensor.

Comment: why would normal usage cause harm?

Comment: TTP223 has an option to choose active low or high. Pin 4.

Answer (score 0):

WS2811 is programmable IC which controls RGB LEDs. It applies NRZ interface to control outside LEDs using PWM. There is some RGB LEDs with integrated WS2811. To control it some MCU should be used. To turn LEDs off completely zeros should be send. What kind of devices usually connected in series, and can be programmed individually